# Solve $\cos(y)\frac{dy}{dx} + \tan(x)\sin(y) = \sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation.

$\cos(y)\frac{dy}{dx} + \tan(x)\sin(y) = \sin(x)$

What would be a suitable substitution to get started?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @HansLundmark's answer, with $w:=\sin y$ we have $w^\prime+Pw=Q$ where $P:=\tan x,\,Q:=\sin x$. The integration factor $R:=\sec x$ then gives$$\sin y=w=\cos x\int\tan x dx=-\cos x\ln|\cos x|+C\cos x$$for a locally constant $C$. (In particular, $C$ can assume one value if $\cos x>0$, but another if $\cos x<0$.) This implicit relation between $x,\,y$ cannot be rearranged to give $y$ as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $w(x)=\sin(y(x))$. Then $w'(x)=\cos(y(x)) \, y'(x)$, and you get a linear equation for $w$.